# Flask-SQLAlchemy unique keyword not reflected in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created this model using Flask-SQLAlchemy and am using it with sqlite:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    public_id = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default=str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-", ""))

db.create_all()
```

However the `unique` keyword doesn't seem to be working, I've created multiple brand new databases with this code and database doesn't seem to register that username needs to be unique. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me

```
sqlite3 database.db
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-15 14:49:49
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> INSERT INTO users (id, email, username, password, public_id) VALUES (1, 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', '1');
INSERT INTO users (id, email, username, password, public_id) VALUES (1, 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', '1');
sqlite> INSERT INTO users (id, email, username, password, public_id) VALUES (1, 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', '1');
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.id
sqlite> INSERT INTO users (id, email, username, password, public_id) VALUES (2, 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', 'a@a.com', '1');
Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username
```

I tried with Flask 1.1.2 and 2.4.4